# What's the easiest way to subset data after visualizing the clusters?

Tags: r

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9N8e.png)

So here I feel I can identify two clusters of data. What is the most effective way to subset this data after visually identifying a cluster? In this data there's conveniently a break at horsepower = 49, but I know not all data is this clean.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question on crossvalidated. But any clustering technique will give you fairly good results just from looking at your data. See `?kmeans`

Comment: try running a kmeans for hclust to identify the cluster ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kmeans` or `hclust` to cluster your data. Then extract the cluster ID, visualize the results and compare them to your own assumptions.  I'm going to use the `mtcars` data to demonstrate

```
# For reproducibility
set.seed(42)

# Perform kmeans clustering, 3 groups
kclusters <- kmeans(mtcars[,c(1,4)], 3)

# Bind together the original data and the clusterID
plot_data <- cbind(mtcars, kclusters$cluster)

# Plot the results and check your own assumptions.
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
   geom_point(aes(color = factor(kclusters$cluster)))
```

[image]